Is there a sequence point between the evaluation of a function's arguments and the assignment of the return value of a function to another object?
Is there a sequence point between the evaluation of a function's arguments and the assignment of the return value of a function to another object?
in other words, is this well defined behavior?
int x = 0;
x += func(++x);

I know that there's a sequence point between the evaluation of the function designator and the function arguments, as well as between the function arguments and the operations within the function, but what about between the function arguments and the assignment of a variable based on the return value of the function itself?
The way the standard is written doesn't give a clear answer to this, and different LLMs give different responses as well.
from the N3096 draft of the C23 standard:

The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:

Between the evaluations of the function designator and actual arguments in a function call and the actual call. (6.5.2.2).
Between the evaluations of the first and second operands of the following operators: logical
AND&&(6.5.13); logical OR || (6.5.14); comma , (6.5.17).
Between the evaluations of the first operand of the conditional ?: operator and whichever of
the second and third operands is evaluated (6.5.15).
Between the evaluation of a full expression and the next full expression to be evaluated. The
following are full expressions: a full declarator for a variably modified type; an initializer that
is not part of a compound literal (6.7.10); the expression in an expression statement (6.8.3); the
controlling expression of a selection statement (if or switch) (6.8.4); the controlling expression
of a while or do statement (6.8.5); each of the (optional) expressions of a for statement (6.8.5.3);
the (optional) expression in a return statement (6.8.6.4).
Immediately before a library function returns (7.1.4).
After the actions associated with each formatted input/output function conversion specifier
(7.23.6, 7.31.2).
Immediately before and immediately after each call to a comparison function, and also between any call to a comparison function and any movement of the objects passed as arguments to that call (7.24.5).



Note that the quote is not from the official ISO/IEC 9899:2024 standard.  Annex C.1 specifies different section numbers: The following are the sequence points described in 5.2.2.4: — Between the evaluations of the function designator and actual arguments in a function call and the actual call. (6.5.3.3). — Between the evaluations of the first and second operands of the following operators: logical
AND && (6.5.14); logical OR || (6.5.15); comma , (6.5.18). … Note the discrepancy between 5.1.2.3 and 5.2.2.4, and between 6.5.2.2 and 6.5.3.3, etc.

Interestingly, N3220 has a hybrid set of numbers (it references 5.1.2.4, 6.5.3.3, 6.5.14, 6.5.15, 6.5.18); N3096 seems to be the draft quoted from (it references 5.1.2.3, 6.5.2.2, 6.5.13, 6.5.14, 6.5.17).  The official standard has a new sub-section 5.1 Introduction which modifies the other references in section 5 (old 5.1 -> 5.2, etc). Similarly, there is a new section 6.5.1 General in the official standard and N3220, but not in N3096, which throws off the later section numbers.

"The way the standard is written doesn't give a clear answer to this, and different LLMs give different responses as well." It's kind of clear, it's just that LLMs actually don't know programming and therefore should not be consulted about such.

This is in fact undefined behavior, due to the use of a compound assignment operator.
An expression of the form a += b is exactly the same as a = a + b, except that a is only evaluated once.  That means that this:
x += func(++x);

Is essentially the same as this:
x = x + func(++x);

And looking at the above, it's clear that the evaluation of x on the left and the side effect of the ++ operator applied to x as a function parameter are unsequenced with respect to each other.
This also means that the following is not undefined behavior:
x = func(++x);

Due to the sequence point introduced by the call to the function func and by the fact that the evaluation of the left side of the assignment doesn't actually use the value.


I know that there's a sequence point between the evaluation of the function designator and the function arguments,…

No, there is not.

… as well as between the function arguments and the operations within the function,…

Yes, more specifically, between evaluation of the function arguments and the function call, per C 2024 6.5.3.3:

… There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call…


… but what about between the function arguments and the assignment of a variable based on the return value of the function itself?

Not explicitly, but the function necessarily contains at least one full expression, in a return statement, and there is a sequence point after that. That sequence point is after the evaluation of the function arguments and prior to the assignment of the x in x += ….
However, none of those are what the compiler is complaining about. The compound assignment x += func(++x) is equivalent to x = x + func(++x) except that the lvalue of x is evaluated only once for the first two appearances of x in that rewriting. So the right side of = contains both a use of x and a separate modification of x (in ++x), and these two operations are not sequenced with respect to each other.

are you confident that there is no sequence point between the evaluation of the function designator and the evaluation of the function arguments? from the c standard: "Between the evaluations of the function designator and actual arguments in a function call and the actual call. (6.5.2.2)."

@Badasahog: You are quoting Annex C, “Sequence points,” which is labeled “informative.” That means it is not part of the normative part of the standard. It is just supplementle summary text. Do not use it for anything but locating information in the actual normative part of the standard. The normative part of the standard the summary refers to contains the text I quoted, “There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call,” which makes it clear where the sequence point is.

that was my mistake, upon further inspection you are correct.
